# How to bind HAProxy with a certificate conditionally

Tags: haproxy

I have this HAProxy configuration in place

```
frontend requests_in
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/private/mycert.pem
```

Then few acl and backends attached to it.

We have two consumers of this frontend - One needs the cert the other doesn't

How can I make this cert bind only valid for certain acls ? Is there a way to do it in the bind line or would I need to create another frontend listening on 443 (if at all possible) ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [crt-list](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#5.1-crt-list) to define how haproxy should behave with different TLS/SSL settings